# Build error for gradle in app

Tags: java, android, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [G:\new\Schat\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\56bf57c0daa4e0ce1427f0af1690a5ff\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

```
Build.gradle 

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sushem.schat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'


}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: I have added build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Use the last version of support library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping. 
The problem was with dependacy :

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'

So i Removed it.

Comment: rather than removing that library, you could have degrade it to version `2.5.+` and that would have solved your problem.

Comment: For more reference you can visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218667/image-cropper-gradle-issue