# Image-Cropper Gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using this library [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and I used it in a project and it works fine now I am using it in another project and in build it fires an error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Work\TeqniaTech\Morstan-Doctor\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\AbdallahGaber.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\d05e3ddb1fe5f53fdf878524820d2b3c\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

and here is my Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teqnia_tech.morstan_doctor"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'

    //location google play service
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'

    //picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //Twitter
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'

    //Timber
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'

    //Butterknife
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

    //Date and time
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'

    // network
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'

    //Twitter
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'

    // for cropping and selecting image
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'

    //Multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
//Map
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and For the project that worked that is the Gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "${project.rootDir}/QA/quality.gradle"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teqnia_tech.morstan"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.5.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // general
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
    // inspection
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.0'
    //Facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'
    // network
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    // tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    //Twitter
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //location google play service
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    //picasso and rounded image
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //Date and time
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    //rtl viewpager
    //    compile 'klogi.com:rtlviewpager:1.0.0'
    //Banner slider
    compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
    //font changer
    //    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    //Searchable spinner
    //    compile 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:1.7'
    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
    //Multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //flexable layout
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    // for filter enhancing
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.0.0'

    // for cropping and selecting image
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

    //AppIntro
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.0'
    compile project(':Spotlight-library')
    compile project(':rtlviewpager')
    compile project(':spinerdialog')
}

//Map
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I spent 2 days and I can't find what is the problem , can anyone help

Edit:
I think the library cause conflict but I can't know what is it, any clue please??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug' android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342094/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug)

Comment: @Zoe , no it's different and the other one is not even solved!

Comment: there are many cases where OP doesn't accept an answer; it doesn't mean the issue hasn't been fixed

Comment: The solutions there not worked for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar problem. But later on I found out that there is one library which is causing that issue.

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
```

Yes. Image Cropping library. When I commented that line and run project after sync, it worked for me.

Now, how to solve that thing? I have found out that some users already posted this issue in Git Link. Please go through below link, it might help you.

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/495

As Described in that post.

**Reason** 
This is due to the fact that this library includes support libraries with 27.+ version. Support library 27.1.0 was released yesterday and is automatically included in your project with another version defined by yourself. The lib must not define dynamic version!

**Solution**
You should force all of your support libraries to use the same version.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { details ->
            // Force all of the primary support libraries to use the same version.
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && details.requested.name != 'multidex'
                    && details.requested.name != 'multidex-instrumentation') {
                details.useVersion supportLibraryVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or, You can downgrade library version from `2.6.+` to `2.5.+`

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
```

Comment: I was entering today to say the answer that worked for me, You are absolutely right and that what I figured when I tried to build the other app for for signed APK, then I found the same error, and then I embedded the library by myself and modified the code when I saw it and realized that the mismatching version is the problem and the problem solved, Thank you Man :)

Comment: @AbdallahGaber Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issues with

```
dependencies {
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
}
```

I changed to

```
dependencies {
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
}
```

It compiled successfully